# How to list down hosts with nmap 5.51

Tags: nmap

I was using nmap 5.21 with the -PN, -F and --reason flags in version 5.21.  I was outputting the results to an XML file.  It would list ALL hosts (say I gave it a /24 subnet to scan.  I then updated to 5.51 and ran the exact same command, but it no longer lists down hosts, just ones that are up.  Is there a new flag to list down hosts?  OR did this get removed in 5.51?

My full options are:

```
-sS -n -PN -SV -F --reason
```

I've also used and removed `--open` but it will not list down hosts in my XML output.

Comment: version 5.21 on RHEL 4 showed up and down hosts when -v verbose was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above suggestions worked.  I had to end up upgrading to 6.01.  Upon doing so the xml output lists ALL hosts:  those that are down and those that are up.

Answer (score 3):

I checked the [Nmap changelog](http://nmap.org/changelog.html) found this in changelog for the Nmap 5.30BETA1 release of March 2010:

> o XML output now only includes host elements for down hosts in verbose
>   mode. This makes it consistent with the other output formats.

So to get the XML output for down hosts like you had before, you should use verbose mode (`-v`) in Nmap 5.30 and newer.

Comment: The -v option is not listing hosts that are down.  I also tried -vvv as well and I'm only getting hosts that are responding.

Comment: Using --open will suppress down hosts, too. Use -v, don't use --open

Comment: I used -v with and without --open and both did not list down hosts....

Answer (score 2):

You can list all hosts by using the `-v` option. Also, the latest version of Nmap is 6.01, which you can download from [nmap.org](http://nmap.org/download.html).